# A button or Link which floats on the side of webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I remember seeing some websites which has some **Live Chat** or **Contact US** links floating in the center-right/center-left side of the screen and clicking on them opens a small form with 1 or 2 input boxes and button.

I want to implement the same and I dont know what they will call these modules so that I can search. Any idea on that?

Comment: you dont need js to position the divs.. CSS will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a div box to have absolution position. by css

```
<style>
.sidebox {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}
</style>

<div id="liveChat" class="sidebox"><a href="#">Live Chat</a></div>
```

finally set the location in JQuery

```
// top left corner
$("#liveChat").css("top", "0");
$("#liveChat").css("left", "0");

// top right corner
$("#liveChat").css("top", "0");
$("#liveChat").css("right", "0");

// bottom right corner
$("#liveChat").css("bottom", "0");
$("#liveChat").css("right", "0");
```

Comment: But why use so many lines of code? `$("#liveChat").css({bottom: 0, right: 0});` Any why set the location in jQuery not CSS anyway?